# About example of infinite Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $E$ be the splitting field for $\{x^2-p: p>0, \mbox{ a prime }\}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. The Galois group of $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is an uncountable group and this is one counterexample for failure of bijection between intermediate fields $\mathbb{Q}\subset L \subset E$ and subgroups of $\mbox{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$.

> Let $\sigma$ be the automorphism given by $\sqrt{p}_i\mapsto -\sqrt{p}_i$ for all primes and let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $\mbox{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ which contains $\sigma$. Then $M$ is a subgroup of index $2$ and it is not Galois group of $E$ over any intermediate field $L$.

**Q.1** Is this assertion correct?

**Q.2** In the above assertion, I wrote "let $M$ be a maximal subgroup containing $\sigma$"; this requires Zorn's lemma. Without Zorn's lemma, can we specify a subgroup which is not the Galois group of $E$ over any intermediate field?

Comment: If you want to prove the failure of the Galois correspondence, it is easier the other way round.  For a prime $p$, let $\sigma_p$ the automorphism which sends $\sqrt{p}$ to $-\sqrt{p}$ and fixes $\sqrt{q}$ for all prime $q\neq p$. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by all the $\sigma_p$'s. For any $\sigma\in H$, it is easy to see that there is only finitely many primes $p$ such that $\sigma(\sqrt{p})=-\sqrt{p}$. Hence $H$ is not the whole galois group. However, it is easily seen that the fixed field of $H$ is $\mathbb{Q}$.
Tell me if you want me to turn this into an answer.

Comment: Dear @GreginGre: I agree that there is no bijection due to sizes of subfields and subgroups. However, I am explicitly looking if some subgroup is not the Galois group over an intermediate field. The above example I thought, and I want to ensure if this example is correct.